# "Import Error: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application" when creating a python package using the Python/C API

Tags: python

I am trying to create a package using the Python/C API. I have followed [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_further_extensions.htm) tutorial, up until the header, "Importing Extensions".

I successfully ran the command `python setup.py install`, which created the pyd file for the package to run, and placed it in a path which is present in `sys.path`.

Then, when I run `import helloworld` I get:

"Import Error: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application".

"helloworld" is the name of the extension module I'm creating (from the tutorial).

I have seen stackoverflow posts with this error, but only when trying to import existing modules. The solution is usually to move a pyd file to the right directory. But I cannot find advice on what to do when this problem arises when creating an extension module.

I am running Windows Server 2012, python 3.6.4 64 bit, on an ipython console (though this problem still occurs when running on a normal python console), using an Anaconda distribution.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling the extension as 64-bit?

Comment: @AKX No, I'm not sure. How can I make sure? The pyd file generated is called "helloworld.cp36-win_amd64.pyd". I assumed that meant it's 64 bit.

Comment: Hmm, well, I would imagine the instructions do create a 64-bit DLL. I've used http://www.dependencywalker.com/ for debugging this sort of problem - use the 64-bit version to debug 64-bit situations and vice versa.